# Xcode EXC_BAD_ACCESS after playing external Video

Tags: xcode, video, external, exc-bad-access

I have a problem with external videos. Whenever I want to play videos from my server, the videos start and work, and when I go back to the page where the video is linked everything is fine. But when I go back to the main menu, the app crashes or better: it crashes at this time, I can't press any button to go back to the main menu.

I am not a programmer, so I would like to know if this has something to do with the xml-file or maybe the project/ active target settings. I am testing the apps on an iPod touch 2nd generation with software version 4.2.1
We already changed the rights on the server, so the videos play.

If it is a programming error, I will have to give it to our programmer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is typically when the code tries to read/write memory no more allocated or never allocated.

Then it is a bug in the application, then a programming error (note the cause can be an error in your XML file not properly handled by the code). In all the cases, contact the programmer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will give it to the programmer.